# Is it possible to tell if writeFile has created a new file in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, fs, writefile

I am creating a new log file every hour, and appending to it as time goes on in a very noisy script that creates a lot of data...

I want to be notified whenever writeFile creates a new file, so I can delete one of the oldest log files that it created.

Is this possible using a callback or anything? Or do I have to create another script that just runs every so often and cleans up old log files?

Comment: When are you creating a new file? Is it every hour or based on a size?

Comment: @JanithaTennakoon Every hour.

Comment: Then you can use the callback of the writeFile to identify when a new file is created.